# No other or any other

Tags: grammar, comparative

We can say : "No other river is longer than the Nile." But can I say : "In my opinion, John Cena is more professional than any other wrestler in WWE."?
I use here "any other" rather than "no other", but There's another question : Can I use in the latter sentence above "no other" rather than "any other"?

Comment: The utterance ***Any** other river is longer than the Nile* is syntactically fine - it's just *manifestly untrue* (it would mean that the Nile is the *shortest* river in the world; if you measured *any* other river it would be longer than the Nile). Equally, *John Cena is more professional than **no** other wrestler in WWE* is syntactically fine - but it means Cena is the ***least*** professional wrestler.

Comment: Speaking about the Nile you might say, "No other river is longer than the Amazon." It means, "Only the Nile is longer than the Amazon".

Comment: If you say John Cena is more professional than **any other** wrestler, then you mean that **whichever** other wrestler (out of all other wrestlers) you pick, John Cena **is** more professional than that randomly chosen other guy. If you say John Cena is more professional than **no other** wrestler, then you are saying that **whichever** other wrestler you pick, (out of all other wrestlers) John Cena is **not** more professional than that other guy.

Comment: As to the accuracy of the other sentence, your mileage may vary. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z88zeQ25pjQ